# Refresh page once for all users

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have about 10 sql queries on a php page. The page responds in about 30 seconds because there are complex queries.

I want to refresh the page every three minutes.

I used a code for this as follows.

```
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "240";
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
```

but if the page is open at 10 users at the same time, it means that it calls sql queries 10 times every three minutes.

what I want is:
If page is only open for one person or 50 people, the page will only run once every three minutes for the sql query. so I want the database to go less.

if the page isn't open in anyone, I don't want it to work at all.

The purpose of this page: to show specific information to the user in the database. The reason I refresh the page is: If the new data comes up when the page is open, the user can see it.

Would you please help with this topic?

Comment: Are the query results cacheable? If so, save them to a cache and update the cache every three minutes. This way you only run the query once no matter how many people view the page.

Comment: So you cache the result somewhere with a timestamp. If the time is less than the limit, that use the data, if it is greater than make a call and than cache it again.

Comment: You could also put them in to a `cache table` in your database, then do a `select * from cache_table` which will return results almost instantly.

Comment: Did you consider fetching the result of each query using AJAX and just refreshing the relevant part of the page as each result is returned

Comment: thank you all.
"Cache table" had come to my mind but there was no "insert into authority" in the same database. I'll do a cache table by creating a cronjob in the background on a different db. So the problem will be solved.

Comment: Instead of a cron job, I would recommend using a `mysql event`.

Comment: I'll create the php file that makes inserting into the cache table as a different page. The user does not even need to have that page open. The page that is open to the user will only be the page that selects from the cache table. Thus, the user will never feel slowness.Don't you think that's more right? In the background, the cronjob will update the cache table every 3 minutes.

Comment: otherwise, the user will still feel the slowness of the select and insert if it is on the same page.

Comment: When I say a `MySQL event`, that is a MySQL version of a cron job. You set when it runs and how often just like a cron job.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I've already used the Mysql event. And the problem is solved. Thanks again to all of you. The page returns response in 2 seconds :))